# Google Sheet Formula Countifs

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to figure out how to add the totals on Sheet 1 of column B if Column D criteria match to Sheet2.

[image: Screenshot]

Example would be adding all of the totals from column B if the criteria "01 Essential" is met.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CtjGA.png

Here is a link to a picture of the sheet I am referencing. I am not yet allowed to upload pictures :(

Comment: Move your mouse over the "google-spreadsheets" tag which you included yourself. A message will pop-up after a while. Read that message aloud.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Sumif`:

```
=Sumif(D:D,"01 Essential",B:B)
```

`D:D` is the reference of Priority Column
`B:B` is the reference of `$` column

Note that if you write `D2:D15` the same number of rows should be for B like `B2:B15` in order to have a correct result.